# large XML to flat Tables Python/Pandas

Tags: python, xml, pandas, xslt, lxml

I am new to XML and trying to convert XML into flat tables to use in python pandas.  What is the recommended way for large files (~150MB, 20000 records). The structure is basically tabular with a few columns having sub levels, so what I would like to produce is one main dataframe and a few linked dataframes (ie with a ID to the main data frame and a extra index for that column).  parsing the xml with lxml and then iterating over each record to compile column lists in order to create a pandas dataframe seems very slow and uses no vectorisation.

I am looking for a method that works well on multiple large files.  Is using xslt to create text files a better solution? would I run it n times - once for each table/nested table, or can one create multiple tables with one xslt script?

```
<record id=100>
    <name>richard<\name>
    <years>
       <yearly index=0>A</yearly>
       <yearly index=1>B</yearly>
    </years>
</record>
```

So in this case I would want to generate two tables - a record dataframe with index id and column 'name' and a 'yearly' dataframe with index (id,index)  and a single column with values 'A','B'

Comment: What do you mean subtables? Pandas does not carry such a structure. Do you mean other dataframes with related IDs. Also, can we see an example XML to illustrate your point?

Comment: I have rephrased the question to use 'dataframes' rather than 'table' Here is an example structure - I was reluctant to put it in because I am interested in a generic solution.

Comment: XML is an open-ended data type, left to the designer's discretion, that can have one to multiple nested nodes with or without multiple attributes whereas txt/csv, db tables, spreadsheets, dataframes are strictly two-dimensions (row by col). So a generic, one-size fits all solution may not be feasible or reliable.

Comment: And XSLT is a good choice for flatfile text conversion that can be imported into pandas and lxml can run dynamic XSLT 1.0 scripts, passing in variables. But XSLT is known to be memory inefficient on large files as it reads entire document at once (newer XSLT 3.0 processors can stream). But 150 MB is not too big and with right CPU environment, XSLT 1.0 should be good enough.